# Loop code of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am learning VBA and would like to loop or change values of for example cell-1 in excel 2007 until cell-2 is equal to cell-3. I have made a macro and a button to activate this but I am struggling to make the code to do this. I do not want the code to activate solver I was hoping a while until loop would do. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post some example data and show what you've already got?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub ChangeValueTilItsGoodEnough()
   Dim r1 as Range, r2 as Range, r3 as Range
   With ThisWorkbook.Sheet("Sheet1")
      'define ranges
      r1 = .Range("A1")
      r2 = .Range("A2")
      r3 = .Range("A3")
      'loop until the two values are equal - may want to add some sort of checker
      'to make sure an infinite loop doesn't happen. I'm assuming you're using 
      'a linear equation tool like Solver.
      While (r2.Value <> r3.Value)
          'change the value of r1
          r1.Value = r1.Value + 1
      Wend
   End With
End Sub
```

Let me know if you have questions.